# A word to describe a concept between 'utopia' and 'dystopia'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word to describe a past experience that is in itself unexplainable, but perceptually vivid in nature and true to the eyes of the beholder. In the first person tense and at first, I reached for 'dystopia', but;

> *noun* dismal imaginary place

Doesn't work, because the reality is not being described as negative, nor positive such as its antonym, 'utopia';

> *noun* ideal place and life

For example;

> The experience was a true _ _ _ , far from reality.

You will have to forgive me, I can see how this question could come across as nonsense. I am open to constructive criticism.

Comment: Topia ---------

Comment: It seems to me that the term you're looking for is "normal".  Or if you want something unfamiliar, without being either good or bad, try looking at antonyms of "deja vu".

Comment: @Harry My pleasure. Good luck!!

Comment: You are describing a key tenet of Existentialism. I would read up on some quotes from Sartre's Nausea

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends a bit on whether the experience that left such a powerful impression was in your head or real; that's to say whether anybody else might have shared it.

An example might be the apparitions of the Virgin Mary experienced by the Portuguese shepherd children at Fatima in 1917.

Any of the following possibilities might apply, depending on context:

> fantasy, mirage, hallucination, apparition, vision, spectre

PS: I was once among a group of people who saw an object in the sky that we could only describe as a flying saucer. We were simply awed.

Answer (score 1):

I will expand upon @RonaldSole's mention of *vision*.

From Dictionary.com:

> [*vision*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vision?s=t): an
>   **experience** in which a personage, thing, or event appears **vividly** or **credibly to the mind**, although not actually present, often under the influence of a divine or other agency
>   [emphasis added]

This matches up well with the wording in your question:

> "I am searching for a word to describe a past **experience** that is
>   in itself unexplainable, but perceptually **vivid** in nature and
>   **true to the eyes of the beholder**. [emphasis added]

Also, *visions* are **unexplainable**, as you mention in your question.

*Vision* could be perfect or out in left field, depending on your context.

Comment: And if the vision lacks focus it could be *myopia*.